# Attach previously uploaded image to post - current code has unexpected results

Tags: php, uploads, attachments

What code currently does:

I feed post id & previously uploaded image id, code processes it all and does its magic described below. Result: **unattached old image** and **new attached image**.

---

What I need it to do:

Attach that **same** image to post as you can do in media screen with few clicks.

---

**Q:** Does anyone know a fix? Or maybe I made a mistakes somewhere? All comments are welcomed!

---

```
//Attach images to post    
$gallery_string = $_POST['my-gallery'];

if( !empty( $gallery_string ) ) {

    //It's a string (e.g '1424,3435,7544,7332') - turn it into array
    $gallery_array = explode(',', $gallery_string);

    foreach( $gallery_array as $value ) {

        //Full path of attachment
        $filename = get_attached_file( $value );

        //Path to the upload directory
        $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

        //Type of file
        $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

        //Prepare an array of post data for the attachment
        $attachment = array(
          'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
          'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
          'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
          'post_content'   => '',
          'post_status'    => 'inherit'
        );

        //Insert the attachment
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $target_post_id );

        //Needed for wp_generate_attachment_metadata()
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

        //Generate the metadata for the attachment and update the database record
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    }
}
```

---

I know that I could use the same image ID and `wp_delete_attachment()` to delete it after "duplication" but still.. Why to make things more complicated if (**IF**) there's a way to just attach it?

I also looked into `upload.php` in wp-admin folder for the action that gets triggered when you press "attach" button in media page but it seems that it can't be used in our code (if it does, it requires pretty big hassle).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit _why_ are you doing it this way? On top of my head attachment is just a post parent designation, this looks like you are doing a complete re-import of existing file or something.

Comment: I'll add some background information to my question as we speak, If you know how to create parent relation / attach already uploaded file to post, be so kind and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachment is just `post_parent` value of the attachment post object, you can update that via `wp_update_post`:

```
foreach( $gallery_array as $value ) {
    $the_post = array(
        'ID'            => $value,
        'post_parent'   => $target_post_id,
    );
    wp_update_post( $the_post );
}
```

Comment: How is this even possible?! There are so many question a'la "how to attach file to post with code" but zero correct answers! Thanks Milo! Super simple and works like a charm.